# How to recognized face which are already detected and saved is local system as .jpg?

Tags: java, opencv, face-recognition

I have used OpenCV, JavaFX to detect and save the face image in local folder. Now I want to recognized face if already saved in local system. I need a some guidance and some sample code or links so I can move further.

**For saving face**

```
Rect rectCrop = null;
    int i =1;
    for (Rect rect : facesArray) {
        Imgproc.rectangle(frame, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        rectCrop = new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);

        Mat image_roi = new Mat(frame,rectCrop);
         Imgcodecs.imwrite("./face"+ i +".jpg",image_roi);
         i++;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code using openCV 3.4

```
static Mat processFace(Net net, Mat img) {
Mat blob = Dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1./255, new Size(96,96), Scalar.all(0), 
true, false);
net.setInput(blob);
return net.forward().clone();
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
// Load the native library.
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

Net net  = Dnn.readNetFromTorch("openface.nn4.small2.v1.t7");

Mat img1 = Imgcodecs.imread("../img/face1.png");
Mat img2 = Imgcodecs.imread("../img/face2.jpg");

Mat feature1 = processFace(net, img1);
Mat feature2 = processFace(net, img2);
double distance = Core.norm(feature1, feature2);
System.out.println("distance: " + distance);
}
```

Comment: add file to your path **openface.nn4.small2.v1.t7**